# pycrypto package installation error - On Linux

Tags: python, linux, pycrypto

Finding the below issue while installing pycrypto 2.6.1 package on linux machine.Installed python version - 3.4.3

```
python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running build_configure
configure: line 18: $'\r': command not found
configure: line 33: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
'onfigure: line 33: `     ;;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 456, in <module>
    core.setup(**kw)
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 251, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 278, in run
    raise RuntimeError("autoconf error")
RuntimeError: autoconf error
```

Can any one help me resolving this?

Comment: Did you try using `pip install pycrypto` ?

Comment: There is no such Python version as "4.3.4"

Comment: There's a python 4?!

Comment: Do you have gcc installed? `apt-get install gcc` for ubuntu/debian, `yum install gcc` for red hat based, `zypper in gcc` for suse.

Comment: Actually its python 3.4.3 . It was mistake.

Comment: @Kishan, cant use pip as I am not having access to internet. I am using package source.

Comment: @Alex, Yes I have gcc installed on machine. gcc (GCC) 4.2.1

Comment: Seems you don't have a working compiler installed.